# Proplem view category in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have 1 project name MVC1

I have 2 classes below:

```
public class category
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class detail
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int CategoryID{get;set;}
}
```

and 2 Intefaces

```
  public inteface ICategory

  {

  IList<category> ListCategory();

  }

  public interface IDetail

  {

  IList<Detail> ListDetail();

  }
```

and 1 Model RCateory inheritance from inteface ICategory

```
   public IList<Category> FindAllCategory()

    {

        List<Category> Listcategory_ = new List<Category>();

        foreach (var category in Listcategory)

        {

            Listcategory_.Add(category);

        }

        return Listcategory_;

    }
```

and 1 Model name RDetail inheritance from inteface IDetail

```
   public IList<Detail> FindAllDetail()

    {

        List<Detail> Listdetail_ = new List<Detail>();

        foreach (var detail in Listdetail_)

        {

            Listdetail_.Add(detail);

        }

        return Listdetail_;

    }
```

and 1 Controller

```
  DetailController

  private RDetail rDetail = new RDetail();

  private RCategory rCategory = new RCategory();

  public ActionResult ListDetail()

  {

  var detail = rdDetail;

  return View("CreateDetail");

  }
```

and 1 View type (cshtml) CreateDetail container

```
  @model MVC1.Detail
```

How do I put into the category to `@Html.DropDownListFor`

Answer (score 0):

As always in an ASP.NET MVC application you start by creating a view model class that will contain everything that your view needs:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Detail Detail { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action populate and pass this view model to the view:

```
public ActionResult ListDetail()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Detail = rDetail;
    model.Categories = FindAllCategory().Select(x => 
        Value = x.ID.ToString(),
        Text = x.Name
    );
    return View("CreateDetail", model);
}
```

and finally your view will become strongly typed to the view model and you will be able to display the dropdown:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Detail.CategoryID, Model.Categories)
```

Comment: not no here ** `rDetail` ** is a _class_ rather than one _attribute_. And ** `FindAllCategory` ** _called_ from ** `rCategory.FindAllCategory` **